# Inequality for $N(0,1)$ CDF: $|\log F(v)|\leq |\log F(0)|+|v|+|v|^2$

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Suppose that $F$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution. Hayashi (2000) claims that the following is true 
>   $$
> |\log F(v)|\leq |\log F(0)|+|v|+|v|^2\quad\text{for all}\quad v.
> $$
>   How does one prove something like this please? I think it looks like it's based on a Taylor approximation but what has happened to the error term?

**Edit 2**: I have plotted
$$
|\log F(0)|+|v|+|v|^2-|\log F(v)|
$$
for $v\in[-25,25]$. It looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: In your partial solution it is not correct that $f'(v)=-f(v)$. In contrast $f'(v)=-vf(v)$. However the case $v\ge 0$ is elementary, since for all $v\ge 0$ the monotonicity of $F$ and $\ln$ imply that $|\ln F(v)|\le |\ln F(0)|$ and therefore of course $|\ln F(v)|\le |\ln F(0)|+|v|+|v|^2$.

Comment: @Stef: Thanks! I've removed it.

Comment: You are welcome!unfortunately I got nothing for v negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{v}_{-\infty}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\,dx$$
$$F(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$
the inequality is equivalent to 
$$|\log F(v)|-|\log(\frac{1}{2})|\leq|v|+|v|^2\Leftrightarrow \log\frac{1}{F(v)}-\log2\leq|v|+|v|^2\Leftrightarrow\log\frac{1}{2F(v)}\leq|v|+|v|^2$$
exponentiating both sides yields
$$\frac{1}{2F(v)}\leq\exp(|v|+|v|^2)\Leftrightarrow 2F(v)\geq \exp(-|v|-|v|^2)$$
Consider the function 
$$G(v)=2F(v)-\exp(-|v|-|v|^2)=2F(v)-\exp(-|v|-v^2)$$
then the problem is equivalent to showing that 
$$G(v)\geq0$$
for all $v\in\mathbb{R}$.
First consider $v\geq0$ then we have
$$G(v)=2F(v)-\exp(-v-v^2)\Rightarrow G'(v)=2F'(v)+(1+2v)\exp(-v-v^2)$$$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})+(1+2v)\exp(-v-v^2)$$
$$=\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})[\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+(1+2v)\exp(-v-\frac{v^2}{2})]\geq0$$
for all $v\geq0$. Therefore 
$$G(v)\geq G(0)=0$$ 
for all $v\in [0,\infty)$.
Secondly let $v<0$ then we obtain
$$G(v)=2F(v)-\exp(v-v^2)\Rightarrow \frac{dG}{dv}=2\frac{dF}{dv}-(1-2v)\exp(v-v^2)$$
$$=\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})[\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-(1-2v)\exp(v-\frac{v^2}{2})]$$
But the function
$$g(v)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-(1-2v)\exp(v-\frac{v^2}{2})\geq g(\frac{-3-\sqrt{17}}{4})>0$$
for all $v\in (-\infty,0)$. Therefore
$$\frac{dG}{dv}=\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})\cdot g(v)>0$$
for all $v\in (-\infty,0)$. Since the derivative is positive in this domain then it must be true that
$$G(v)\geq \lim_{v\to-\infty}G(v)=\lim_{v\to-\infty}\{2F(v)-\exp(v-v^2)\}=0$$
for all $v\in (-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @Kim: You're welcome! :)